# Error : cannot convert ‘std::vector<float>’ to ‘float’ in initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, error-handling, stdvector

I have defined a vector of the `boundary_info` structure as `std::vector<boundary_info> nodes` to be used in my code for a specific purpose. While I try to `push_back` new elements into this vector in a specific function as:

```
void myFun()
{
   std::vector<float_type> dists(9, -1.0);
   std::array<float_type,9> f, g;

   //do something - x and y are defined here

   nodes.push_back(boundary_info{point<int>{x,y}, dists, f, g, {}});
}
```

I get the following error message :

```
Error 1 : cannot convert ‘std::vector<float>’ to ‘float’ in initialization
Error 2 : cannot convert ‘std::array<float, 9ul>’ to ‘float’ in 
initialization
Error 3 : cannot convert ‘std::array<float, 9ul>’ to ‘float’ in 
initialization
```

Error 1 is associated with `dists`, which is a vector. Errors 2 and 3 are associated with the `f, g` passed as parameters in `push_back` respectively. 
The code is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct point //specify a point structure
{
  T x,y;
};

struct boundary_info
{  
  point<int> xy_bdary; //coordinates of a bdary point
  std::array<float_type,9> dist; //distance from boundary 
  std::array<float_type,9> f_prev, g_prev; //populations 
  std::vector<int> miss_dirns; //missing directions 
};
```

I would be glad if the solution for this error would be pointed out. I have been struggling with it since half a day.

**Note** : I am compiling using c++11.

**Edit**
You can find a minimal code of this problem reproducing the same problem at
https://repl.it/repls/GleefulTartMarkuplanguage

Thanks

Comment: Check the order of the parameters

Comment: When initializing `boundary_info` you pass a `std::vector` for `std::array`.

Comment: If you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks a lot for your suggestion, which worked out like a charm. I was of the opinion that a vector of 9 size should work the same, as that of an array!

Comment: @GoranFlegar I have edited the post with the link of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line you are trying to initialize a `std::array` (`boundary_info::dist`) from a `std::vector` (`dists`):

```
nodes.push_back(boundary_info{point<int>{x,y}, dists, f, g, {}});
```

`std::array` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `std::vector`. You could only initialize the `std::array` element-wise (aggregate initialization) or explicitly copy the `std::vector` to the `std::array`.

## Aggregate initialization

```
nodes.push_back(boundary_info{point<int>{x,y}, {dists[0], dists[1], dists[2], dists[3], dists[4], dists[5], dists[6], dists[7], dists[8]}, f, g, {}});
```

Of course, that's not very elegant.

## Copy `std::vector` to `std::array`

With the help of a little template function, we can do better.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Range>
std::array<T,N> to_array( Range const& in )
{
    std::array<T,N> result;

    // To make the standard begin() and end() in addition to any user-defined
    // overloads available for ADL.
    using std::begin; using std::end;

    std::copy( begin( in ), end( in ), result.begin() );

    return result;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dV1Qv2ah8r76iukM)

`to_array` accepts any input type that has `begin()` and `end()` member functions or overloads of the free functions `begin()` and `end()`.

Now you can initialize the array from the vector like this:

```
nodes.push_back(boundary_info{point<int>{x,y}, to_array<float_type,9>(dists), f, g, {}});
```

Note that you can easily shoot yourself in the foot if `dists` has more elements than the array, because `to_array` doesn't do any range checking (`std::copy` doesn't do either). I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to make the function more secure, if needed.